# Выбор почтового клиента

Tags: python, email, кроссплатформенность, c++

У меня имеется система, написанная на С++ в стили С, которая должна в определенный момент отсылать сообщение на почту пользователю. Система кросс платформенная, собирается под Windows, Mac, Linux. Вопрос такой, какого кросс платформенного почтового клиента взять? Или, возможно, стоит написать своего? Если писать своего клиента, то на чем, на С++, Python или другом языке?

Comment: А зачем нужен почтовый клиент для отправки сообщений?

Comment: А чем Вы предлагаете воспользоваться?

Comment: Можно просто написать скрипт на Python, который будет отправлять email сообщения. А полноценный почтовый клиент - это излишества

Comment: Это уже предложил Alexeyxo. По сути это и будет почтовый клиент. Просто, в решении с Python мы будем вызвать его как создание нового процесса, а в случае решения на С++ просто вызов ф-и. Если с С++ понятно как отследить результат выполнения, то с Python надо еще подумать.

Comment: Почтовый клиент - это больше, чем просто скрипт, отсылающий сообщения.

Comment: Решение должно быть масштабируемое.

Comment: По-моему, saigono прав. Чтобы отправить сообщение нужен просто скрипт на Питоне. Кстати, первый вопрос на форуме как раз о том, как послать письмо из Питона с вложением - http://hashcode.ru/questions/1/

Answer (score 3):

А почему вообще встаёт вопрос о реализации отправки на каком-то другом языке? Для Linux я использую [эту библиотеку](http://etpan.org/libetpan.html) (pure C). Вроде бы и под Windows, и под Mac она собирается, не пробовал. Во всяком случае такие таргеты в исходниках есть :) Есть и что попроще, [libquickmail](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libquickmail/), например (C, SMTP), или [CSmtp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28806/SMTP-Client) (C++, SMTP). Правда, в 2 последних Mac не заявлен.

Answer (score 0):

напишите на ява - 1 раз написали - а потом требуйте просто чтобы на машине была ява и нужные сервисы (если сообщение будете слать не вручную через сокеты а через эти сервисы)- погуглить надо - отправление сообщений на java.
ответ аналогичен предыдущему - там на питоне вроде советовали => питоновские библиотеки надо. а у меня - ява :) - кто что знает.
если предпочтения С++ - то надо либо рыть библиотеки соответвующие - я ими не пользоваля. возможно стоит порыть в сторону QT

Answer (score 0):

Для начала можно просто реализовать запуск внешнего приложения с параметрами и передачей тела сообщения через его STDIN. Это позволит использовать внешние приложения командной строки типа mail или sendmail, равно как и скрипты на python или perl.

Написать клиентскую часть протокола SMTP на C++ тоже не слишком сложно, если умеете работать с tcp соединениями. Сам протокол прост, ответы сервера вполне возможно разобрать и в коде на C++, примеры кода с реализацией MD5 (для реализации аутентификации отправителя) в сети тоже есть.