# Отправка почты C++

Tags: c++, curl, email, winsock, smtp

Как лучше организовать отправку почты на с++,
сейчас почти все почтовые сервисы перешли на ssl,
думал делать на curl, но увы при компиляции либ файлов все зависает.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, сейчас он ни о чём. Этакие мысли в слух.

Comment: В \*nix я бы посоветовал по-простому вызывать команду `mail`. / Однако, тэг `winsock` подсказывает, что все не так просто...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите ссылки здесь: [выбор почтового клиента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1627/). Для себя я допиливал библиотеку из [этого кода](https://github.com/deanproxy/eMail), если интересно могу поделиться (pure C). Но всё зависит от ваших потребностей (мне нужно было только либо письма из одной части, либо multipart/alternative плюс аттачи, полноценной поддержки всего, что может быть в MIME, там нет. Ну и из чарсетов только UTF-8 и US-ASCII понимает). TLS она умеет, и под Windows, и под Linux.